# Firebase Notifications not Displaying in Notification Bar When App is Open on android 13 & above

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

firebase notification is not showing on the notification bar when the app is open. But notification is received and this message can be shows on the console. I am using flutterlocalnotification package for this handling foreground notification .This is the Flutter application.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
print("foregroundMsg:${message.notification?.title}");
print("foregroundMsg:${message.notification?.body}");
print("foregroundMsg1:${message.notification}");
showLocalNotification(
    0, message.notification?.title ?? '', message.notification?.body ?? '');



try {
print("foreground2 ${message.notification?.title}");
CheckInternet().getUnreadNotificationCount();

await NotificatioDb.instance.insertNotification(
      "${message.notification?.title}",
      "${message.notification?.body}",
      "${message.data['time']}",
      "${message.data['url']}",
      "${message.data['reloadFlag']}");
print("foreground3 ${message.notification?.title}");
} catch (e) {
print("foreground4 ${message.notification?.title}");
print("backgroundErrorlisten $e");
}
});


}
```

> This is my code for the function showLocalnotification()

```
Future<void> showLocalNotification(int id, String title, String body) async {
print('Background message received');
print("Bacground:$title");
print("Bacground:$body");
var androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
'channelId',
'channelName',
'channelDescription',
importance: Importance.high,
priority: Priority.high,
);

var iosDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();

var generalNotificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
android: androidDetails,
iOS: iosDetails,
);
```

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
id,
title,
body,
generalNotificationDetails,
payload: 'notificationPayload',
);

```
print("Background show");
```

}

> This is the code i used to handle background notification from firebase. it is properly working and notification is showing on the notification bar.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage 
message) async {
showLocalNotification(
  0, message.notification?.title ?? '', message.notification?.body 
?? '');


try {
CheckInternet().getUnreadNotificationCount();

await NotificatioDb.instance.insertNotification(
      "${message.notification?.title}",
      "${message.notification?.body}",
      "${message.data['time']}",
      "${message.data['url']}",
      "${message.data['reloadFlag']}");
} catch (e) {
print("backgroundError $e");
}
}
```

> And it is called in main() function

Comment: Can you share from where you are sending notification.? Also please check the payload you sent is notification or data. Because both have different behaviour.

Comment: title and message is sending through notification, and there other values are sending through data